# python scripting - determine if dopesheet actions are collapsed

Tags: python, animation, scripting, interface, add-on

In the dopesheet editor, there is a tree-like list of channels on the left side.

In python, you can figure out if a specific group of channels is expanded or not like this:

```
obj = bpy.data.objects['Armature.001']
group = obj.animation_data.action.groups[0]
temp = group.show_expanded
```

Then `temp` would be a boolean which is true when the list of all the transform channels is open, and false when the list of channels is collapsed.

Below is a screenshot with various objects that have animations in actions. The first two objects have collapsed channel groups, but the final "Object Transforms" group is expanded.

[image]

This works great for groups, but the UI also has arrows that allow for collapsing entire actions and entire objects. You can even click the arrow next to "Summary" at the top and collapse everything.

How do you query from Python whether an object or action is expanded or not? Is this possible?